# How to have Yocto checking my file has been changed

Tags: yocto

I have a bb file that will install a file into rootfs:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Add file to rootfs"
LICENSE = "test"

CONF_FILE = "${TOPDIR}/../meta/meta-test/recipes-test/test_file"

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}/home/root
        install -m 755 ${CONF_FILE} ${D}/home/root
}

FILES_${PN} += "/home/root"
```

It works fine and I can see my file in /home/root

Then I modify the file and build again.
But I find that the file isn't changed.

How can I have Yocto to check this file and build-in every time when it's changed?

Comment: Maybe put it in SRC_URI to force checksum creation?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nayfe.
It's been solved after adding SRC_URI

```
DESCRIPTION = "Add file to rootfs"
LICENSE = "test"

CONF_FILE = "${TOPDIR}/../meta/meta-test/recipes-test/test_file"
SRC_URI = ${CONF_FILE}

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}/home/root
        install -m 755 ${CONF_FILE} ${D}/home/root
}

FILES_${PN} += "/home/root"
```